# How to send audio recorded in Android to Microsoft's Speaker Recognition API?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I've stumbled upon many solutions to this question but most are either outdated or don't work with SDK 26 in android.
I'm trying to consume [Microsoft's Speaker recognition API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/) through an android client. 
The sample MS provided is as below :-

```
public class JavaSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/{identificationProfileId}/enroll");

            builder.setParameter("shortAudio", "{boolean}");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");


            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But since org.apache.http libraries have been deprecated in SDK versions 23 and above I'm not sure what exactly to use.

NOTE :- Some solutions have suggested using HTTPURLConnection but none explains how to add content type (octet-stream) accurately.

Since I'm very new to Android, please pardon any naivety in the question.

Thank you all in advance!